# JQuery DataTables, change pagination inside function

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, datatables, pagination

I am trying to change pagination inside function where I am getting data from DataTables, I would like get data with all choosen ffilters but without pagination.

DataTable

```
  let $table = $('.table-orders').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/ajax/get_shipments',
      // dataSrc: '',
      // cache: false,
      // context: document.body,
    },
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    searching: true,
    paging: true,
    ordering: true,
    order: [
      [0, 'desc'],
    ],(...)

   methods: {
      filterData: filterData,
      generateReport: function () {
        $table.paging = false; #<-- here is what I tried, but it doesn't work.
        let data = $table.ajax.params();
        data.generate = true;
        $.get('/ajax/get_shipments', data, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    },
  });
```

I am quite new in JavaScript and do not have big idea how functions in JS works. I'm sure is there simple way to do that, but have no idea where to find it.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want pagination? You want all the result in 1 page?

Comment: Yes and no. I want results paginated as it is visible in the page. But after use generateRaport function I would like to get all results without pagination.

Comment: You will need to do something on the back end (whatever is processing /ajax/get_shipments) to look at your parameter and not paginate.

Comment: You would like to 'get' all results without pagination or you would like to 'show' all results without pagination?